# How to create and parse if statements in Antlr 4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, language-design

So, I just started learning antlr4 and I just made an extremely simple programming language. The language can create variables (int, booleans, and strings), change their values, and output their values. However, I am trying to do an if statement but after many tries, it didn't work. Googling didn't help either since most of the others code is too different to understand and apply it on my own. Most of my code follow this tutorial:

https://progur.com/2016/09/how-to-create-language-using-antlr4.html

Here's my grammar file

```
grammar valhallap;

program : 'begin' statement+ 'end';

ifState : ifDec 'STARTIF' statement+ 'ENDIF';



statement :  createINT|assign|addINT|printVar|createString|print|createBool|;




ifDec: 'if' (NUMBER|ID) EXPRESION (NUMBER|ID) 'then';
createINT : 'new' 'int' ID;
createBool: 'new' 'bool' ID;
createString : 'new' 'string' ID;
addINT : 'addINT' ID NUMBER;
assign : 'set' ID (STRING|BOOL|NUMBER);
print : 'output' 'say' STRING;
printVar : 'output' 'var' ID;





ID : [A-z]+;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
STRING : ["] ( ~["\r\n\\] | '\\' ~[\r\n] )* ["] | ['] ( ~['\r\n\\] | '\\' ~[\r\n] )* ['];
BOOL : 'true' | 'false';
WS : [ \n\t]+ -> skip;
Comment: '**' ~( '\r' | '\n' )* -> skip;
STATEMENT : .;
EXPRESION:
     'MORETHAN'
     |'LESSTHAN'
     |'EQUALS'
     |'LESSEQUALS'
     |'MOREEQUALS';
```

Finally here's the listener class

```
import com.power.valhallap.grammar.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */

public class ValhallaListener extends valhallapBaseListener{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
private Map<String, Object> variables;
public static boolean ifState = false;

public ValhallaListener()
{
    //init all the variables
    variables = new HashMap<>();
}


//if statements



@Override
public void exitAssign(valhallapParser.AssignContext ctx)
{
    String variable = ctx.ID().getText();


    if(variables.get(variable) instanceof String)
    {
        if(ctx.NUMBER() != null || ctx.BOOL() != null)
        {`enter code here`
            System.out.println("error expecting string");
        }
    }
    if(variables.get(variable) instanceof Boolean)
    {
        if(ctx.NUMBER() != null || ctx.STRING() != null)
        {
            System.out.println("error expecting boolean");
        }
    }
    if(variables.get(variable) instanceof Integer)
    {
        if(ctx.STRING() != null || ctx.BOOL() != null)
        {
            System.out.println("error expecting integer");
        }
    }

    if(ctx.STRING() != null)
    {
        if(variables.get(variable) instanceof String)
        {
           String finalString = ctx.STRING().getText();
           finalString = finalString.replace("\"", "");
           variables.put(variable, finalString);
        }

    }

    if(ctx.NUMBER() != null)
    {
        if(variables.get(variable) instanceof Integer)
        {
           variables.put(variable, Integer.parseInt(ctx.NUMBER().getText()));
        }

    }

    if(ctx.BOOL() != null)
    {
        if(variables.get(variable) instanceof Boolean)
        {
           boolean answer = Boolean.parseBoolean(ctx.BOOL().getText());

           variables.put(variable, answer);
        }

    }


}

@Override
public void exitCreateINT(valhallapParser.CreateINTContext ctx)
{
    //get's the variable name of int
    String variableName = ctx.ID().getText();

     if(!variables.containsKey(variableName))
    {
        //add the name to the hashmap with the init value of 0
        variables.put(variableName, 0);
    }
}



@Override
public void exitAddINT(valhallapParser.AddINTContext ctx)
{
    //get the var name
    String varName = ctx.ID().getText();

    //get the value
    int first = Integer.parseInt(variables.get(varName).toString());

    int addValue = Integer.parseInt(ctx.NUMBER().getText());

    int finalValue = first + addValue;

    //assign the new value

    variables.put(varName, finalValue);
}


 @Override
public void exitPrintVar(valhallapParser.PrintVarContext ctx)
{
    String varName = ctx.ID().getText();



    System.out.println(variables.get(varName));
}

@Override
public void exitPrint(valhallapParser.PrintContext ctx)
{
    String output = ctx.STRING().getText();
    output = output.replace("\"", "");
    System.out.println(output);
}

@Override
public void exitCreateString(valhallapParser.CreateStringContext ctx)
{
    String variableName = ctx.ID().getText();


    if(!variables.containsKey(variableName))
    {
        //add the name to the hashmap with the init value of null
        variables.put(variableName, "");
    }
}



@Override
public void exitCreateBool(valhallapParser.CreateBoolContext ctx)
{
    //get's the variable name of int
    String variableName = ctx.ID().getText();

     if(!variables.containsKey(variableName))
    {
        //add the name to the hashmap with the init value of false
        variables.put(variableName, false);
    }
}





public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
    ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(args[0]));    

    valhallapLexer lexer = new  valhallapLexer(input);
    valhallapParser parser = new valhallapParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.addParseListener(new ValhallaListener());

    // Start parsing
    parser.program();


    if(ifState)
    {
        parser.ifState();
    }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The syntax of the if statement that I want to achieve is:

```
begin
if 5 MORETHAN 4 then
   .....
ENDIF
end
```

I new to the antlr4 and some of the concepts are new to me, it would be great if anyone could help me thanks!

Comment: "It didn't work" tells us nothing. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So, my program starts to parse the 'statement' which is in between a 'begin' and 'end' keyword. So what I've tried was to call the 'statement' in the grammar file after the then keyword and will be executed if the if statement returns true. However, I can't stop the parser from parser through the if statement. In other words, the parser just ignores the if statement and parses everything. So I think there must be other ways since I saw many different examples on the internet, but I just need some explanation on all of that.

Comment: Better solve your problems step by step. Your problem is not the listener. Your problem is understanding of parsing. If you want to use an if statement between `begin...end` you should allow it as statement (rather than parsing it explictly, depending on a static variable `ifState`. Please reduce your example to your main problem. Nobody will mind if you ask another question when your first problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

`ifState` isn't mentioned in your `statement` rule.

Also, keep in mind that you defined that there should be 'STARTIF' after `THEN` - it's not in your example input.

And another observation, your `statement` rule ends with `|;` - this means it allows empty statement. This doesn't make sense in a language with no statement separator.

#### Edit

As @CoronA pointed out, the problem is that you first call `program` rule in your main and then call `ifState`. Doing so means you expect to first parse the program (beginning with `begin` and ending with `end`) and *only then* you instruct the parser to parse the if statement. So the input that would be parsed by your current code would have to be something like:

```
begin
    ...
end
if 5 MORETHAN 4 then
STARTIF
   ...
ENDIF
```

What you probably want to do is make `ifState` just another possible statement type, i.e. add it to `statement` rule and call only `program` from main.

Comment: `ifState` is explicitly called in main. Does not really make sense to call `program` and `ifState` in sequence.

Comment: @Jiri Tousek@CoronA, thanks! for making it more understandable to me. However, after trying to do the same thing as you said, I am having a problem trying to skip the statement inside the ifState. For example, the if condition returns false and I want to skip and continue on with the program, how will I do it? Is there a specific function that allows me to skip the 'statement' and move on?

Comment: Do you mean that if the condition is false, the inside can be non-valid code? That would be difficult to do. If you mean the ordinary semantics (i.e. code must be valid but won't be executed if condition is false), that's something you handle in the listener, not in parser.

Comment: @Jiri Tousek, well yes that is what I am saying, but I am not sure on how to do it in the listener class, I tried using the context.statement().remove(0), but it still didn't work. Either it gives me an error or it just simply didn't work.